# while checking checkbox value is increasing or decreasing but it works for only one check box, in should work for every checkbox( Plain Javascripr)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51K5J.png)

it is working for only one checkbox but i want to work for every check box because id is same as 1st checkbox

Here is my code:

```js
function addRightAnswer(){
var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.getElementById('checkCheckbox');

if (document.getElementById('checkCheckbox').checked)
  {
    document.getElementById('get-radio-input-number').value=1;
  } 
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('get-radio-input-number').value=0;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content"><span class="close" onclick="closeModal();">&times;</span>
    <div class="model-layout">
        <p>Enter question</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="radio-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Question"
                    required autofocus></div>
            <p>Enter Your Option and Points</p>
            <div class="form-group" id="divFectchAllQuestion">
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkCheckbox" name="checkCheckbox"
                        onclick="addRightAnswer(this);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"
                        class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input1" name="get-radio-input" value=""><input
                        type="number" id="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" /><button
                        type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" disabled><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkCheckbox" name="checkCheckbox"
                        onclick="addRightAnswer(this);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"
                        class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input" name="get-radio-input"><input
                        type="number" id="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" /><button
                        type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkCheckbox" name="checkCheckbox"
                        onclick="addRightAnswer(this);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"
                        class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input3" name="get-radio-input"><input
                        type="number" id="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" /><button
                        type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkCheckbox" name="checkCheckbox"
                        onclick="addRightAnswer(this);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"
                        class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input4" name="get-radio-input"><input
                        type="number" id="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" /><button
                        type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
            </div><label for="radio-group-required"><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox"
                    id="radio-group-required">Make this question compulsory</label>
            <div class="select-page form-group">
                <p>Select Page</p><select id="line-page-no" name="line-page-no"
                    class="page-options form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit"
                    onclick="addRadioGroup();"></div>
        </form>
        <p id="radio-error-message"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give html code. I will give you an example using the `forEach()` method.

Comment: <input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox" id="checkCheckbox" name="checkCheckbox"  onclick="addRightAnswer(this);">                                                                This one is number field                       <input type="number" id="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input"/>

Comment: do all your `inputs` have the same `id`? - `id = "checkCheckbox"`

Comment: yes, all id is same

Comment: Number field id is also same

Comment: It is not right. The `id` attribute must be unique for each element.

Comment: for checkbox field ony id is same

Comment: Each checkbox field must have a unique `id`. You can insert a little more html code here so that I can make an example for you and correct the identifiers.

Comment: You can paste your code by editing your question.

Comment: ok, i am pasting

Comment: please see above code.. i have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html you use the same `id` for all inputs - this is not valid for html! Each item must have a unique `id`. I removed all id from your input using the class for reversal in the js code.

Also, your second iputs with the number also had the same `id`. This is also a mistake. I replaced with class. Like this:

```
class="get-radio-input-number"
```

Now by the code js... I wrote the logic for displaying the value in the input, using the `forEach()` method, which identifies the inputs by the `[index]` parameter.

```js
window.onload = function() {
let getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox');
let getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');

  getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
    current.addEventListener('click', function() {

      if (current.checked) {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1;
      } 
      else
      {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
      }  

    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content"><span class="close" onclick="closeModal();">&times;</span>
    <div class="model-layout">
        <p>Enter question</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="radio-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Question"
                    required autofocus></div>
            <p>Enter Your Option and Points</p>
            <div class="form-group" id="divFectchAllQuestion">
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="checkCheckbox"><input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input1"
                        name="get-radio-input" value=""><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
                        name="get-radio-input" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" disabled><i
                            class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="checkCheckbox"><input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input"
                        name="get-radio-input"><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
                        name="get-radio-input" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click"
                        onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="checkCheckbox"><input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input3"
                        name="get-radio-input"><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
                        name="get-radio-input" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click"
                        onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="checkCheckbox"><input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input4"
                        name="get-radio-input"><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
                        name="get-radio-input" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
                            class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click"
                        onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div><label for="radio-group-required"><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox"
                    id="radio-group-required">Make this question compulsory</label>
            <div class="select-page form-group">
                <p>Select Page</p><select id="line-page-no" name="line-page-no"
                    class="page-options form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit"
                    onclick="addRadioGroup();"></div>
        </form>
        <p id="radio-error-message"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still one bug 1st clicking on checkbox it is showing '0' as it is, after another  click it is showing 1

Comment: can you please do it this on onclick function()?

Comment: Hello. But works well for me. You need to make `html` code, like in my example. And don't use the same `id` for everyone. What do you mean for the `onclick()` function?