# Make a checkbox checked or unchecked based on the number increment? (only in plain javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we make a checkbox checked or unchecked programatically based on the increment number? If the number is 1 then the checkbox is checked and if the number is 0 then the checkebox is unchecked?

My html code

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();" >
<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input" >
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

My Js code
In this code I click on the checkbox then increase the number but I also want that if the number is increased then the checkbox to be automatically checked.

```
 function addRightAnswer() {
      var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
      var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');
    
      getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
    
          if (current.checked) {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1; //
          } else {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
          }
    
      });
         
    }
```

Comment: I remember doing this code for you for many inputs. Have you changed your concept now? Need to check the box if the value is 1? What should happen if the number is greater than 1? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445623/while-checking-checkbox-value-is-increasing-or-decreasing-but-it-works-for-only/65445873?noredirect=1#comment115714052_65445873

Comment: if number is greater than 1 checkbox is checked if 0 then uncheck

Comment: but now i want both if increasing the number checkbox should be checked

Comment: can you please do it  @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: I gave you a solution. Check it out. Was such a result necessary?

Comment: can you please check again. i am facing some issue, please check above requirement @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: Why did you strip my answer as solved? After all, I answered your main question. And your second problem is as an additional question.

Comment: yes this is the additional question

Comment: please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474770/checkbox-increasing-and-decreasing-problem @sergeykuznetsov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a simple if value is 1 do it, let's see my example:

```js
function addRightAnswer() {
      var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
      var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');
    
      getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
    
          if (current.checked) {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1; //
          } else {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
          }
    
      });
         
    }
function Checked(el){
  var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelector('.input-checkbox-correct');
  if(el.value > 0){
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.checked = true;
  }else{
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.checked = false;
  }


}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();" ><input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input" >
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" min="0" max="1" onChange="Checked(this)" name="get-radio-input"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)">
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

I add a function Checked with onchange in the input and always in the input i add `min="0" max="1"` because seems like you need only that.

---

edit after your comment:

```js
function addRightAnswer() {
      var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
      var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');
    
      getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
    
          if (current.checked) {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1; //
          } else {
            getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
          }
    
      });
         
    }
function Checked(){
  var input1 = document.querySelector('#get-radio-input');
  var input2 = document.querySelector('#get-radio-input5');
  var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelector('.input-checkbox-correct');
  if(input1.value > 0 || input2.value > 0){
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.checked = true;
  }else{
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.checked = false;
  }


}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();" ><input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input" onChange="Checked()">
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" id="get-radio-input" value="0" min="0" max="1" id="get-radio-input5" onChange="Checked()" name="get-radio-input"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)">
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

In this case i did a check in both input.