# checkbox increasing and decreasing problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now I am facing an issue if the 1st checkbox number is increasing then click on the 2nd checkbox then 1st checkbox value will display 1 it should be as it is where I have increased by 4 or 5 but it will display automatically 1 by checking another checkbox

My Js code In this code I click on the checkbox then increase the number but I also want that if the number is increased then the checkbox to be automatically checked.

```js
function addRightAnswer(element, index) {
var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');
  if (element.checked) {
    getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1;
  } else {
    getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
  }         
}

function setCheckBox(element, index) {
var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
  if (element.value > 0) {
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck[index].checked = true;
  } else {
    getRadioOptionsNumberCheck[index].checked = false;
  }       
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content"><span class="close" onclick="closeModal();">&times;</span><div class="model-layout"><p>Enter question</p><form onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="radio-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Question" required autofocus></div><p>Enter Your Option and Points</p><div class="form-group" id="divFectchAllQuestion"><div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer(this, 0);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input1" name="get-radio-input" value=""><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox(this, 0);" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" disabled><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer(this, 1);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input" name="get-radio-input" ><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox(this, 0);" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer(this, 1);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input3" name="get-radio-input" ><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox(this, 0);" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer(this, 1);"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input4" name="get-radio-input" ><input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox(this, 0);" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div><label for="radio-group-required"><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" id="radio-group-required">Make this question compulsory</label><div class="select-page form-group"><p>Select Page</p><select id="line-page-no" name="line-page-no" class="page-options form-control"></select></div><div class="form-group"><input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit" onclick="addRadioGroup();"></div></form><p id="radio-error-message"></p></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi There! I could understand your problem fully. Could you explain me more what you want to achieve from the code :)

Comment: You don't want the first checkbox to change value based on what happens in other checkboxes. Is it what you want... Can you share an image about what you actually want to achieve ? Thank you

Comment: no, i want if i checked then number is increase by 1 id uncheck number will 0 @ImranRafiqRather

Comment: please do @sergeykuznetsov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want like this?

-html

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox1" onclick="addRightAnswer(this);" >
<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input1" >
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox2" onclick="addRightAnswer(this);" >
<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input2" >
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

-js

```
 function addRightAnswer(checkbox) {
   var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
   var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');
    var i=0;
getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
  if(checkbox == current)  i=index; });
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    getRadioInputNumber[i].value = 1; //
  } else {
    getRadioInputNumber[i].value = 0;
  }

}
function setCheckBox() {

  var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
  var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');

      getRadioInputNumber.forEach(function(current, index) {
          if (current.value > 0) {
            getRadioOptionsNumberCheck[index].checked = true;
          } else {
            getRadioOptionsNumberCheck[index].checked = false;
          }

      });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();" >
<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input">
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<input type="checkbox"  class="input-checkbox-correct"  name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();" >
<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input" >
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/>
<button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: what you have changed in it?

Comment: you call "setCheckBox()" function in different input tag

Comment: so, what i have to do?

Comment: change only two line in html

Comment: like this.                                                                                                                     
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input">
<input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/>

Comment: see second line and third line at your html code. it's wrong

Comment: <input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" onChange="setCheckBox();"/> what you have changed in this line

Comment: look at the second line at html you posted

Comment: delete  onChange="setCheckBox()" and inset that to third line

Comment: i have changed according to you but it is not workong

Comment: i 've posted another answer. confirm